# Facebook losing logged in user with ajax

Tags: ajax, facebook

I am writing a Facebook app and have used the Facebook php SDK so it can be authorized server side. I can see this is working because after authorization when Facebook redirects back to my app, I have the following code in my index.php...

```
require_once 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '111111111111111',
    'secret' => '11111111111111111111111111111111',
    'cookie' => true
));
    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
```

...and $user returns not null. So far, so good!

I have a link on my app that loads content via ajax when clicked. Here's the JS:

```
$.post('my_content.php', {
    action: 'render'
}, function(res){
    if (res.html.length) {              
        $('.content').html(res.html);
    }
},'json');
```

The problem is, the my_content.php script seems to be losing the fact the user has logged in and authorized the app.

The code I run in the my_content.php script to check whether the user is logged in is the same as in index.php

```
require_once 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '111111111111111',
    'secret' => '11111111111111111111111111111111',
    'cookie' => true
));
    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
```

This time though `$user = $facebook->getUser()` returns null.

Is there a way to check if the user is logged in and authorized when running a PHP script with an AJAX call?

Should I store something in a session variable in my index.php script?

**EDIT**

After even more reading, I'm wondering if I need to retrieve the access token using the JavaScript SDK and pass it to my_content.php. Does anyone know if that's the correct way to do it?

**EDIT 2**

Turns out the line giving me the problem isn't `$user = $facebook->getUser()`:

It is this one

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

This line fails with the error 'OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.'

Strangely though, if I do this

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$user = $facebook->getUser();

echo $access_token;
echo $user;
```

I do indeed have an access token and a user ID, so it looks like it may well be the bug reported by CBroe - check comments below.

Comment: Might be the same as here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13635991/an-active-access-token-must-be-used-dec-2012-the-proper-way-to-set-up-fac#comment18728737_13635991 (Check if disabling the migration makes it go away to confirm)

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I've tried disabling December 2012 Breaking Changes and January 2013 Breaking Changes but I still have the same problem

Comment: Looking in my server error log, I see the same message 'OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user'